Read a variable from a .ps1 file and run a .ps1 script inside Pipeline with Git Repo
I am using Azure DevOps repos, and I am working on a pipeline. I want it to read a variable from config.ps1 file and set a env variable with it. After that I want to run a powershell script. It gives errors with the path and reading the parameters.
I would like to instead of reading this config.yml and install this module, I would like to have something more straightforward like a config.ps1 just stating the variable. Then retrieve that variable here and assign it to an env variable.
trigger:
- main
- test

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  MES_SERVER_USERNAME: '$(SERVER_USERNAME)'
  MES_SERVER_PASSWORD: '$(SERVER_PASSWORD)'
  TEST_SERVER_IP: '$(TEST_IP)'
  PROD_SERVER_IP: '$(PROD_IP)'

stages:
  - stage: DeployToServer
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployToTest
        displayName: 'Deploy to Test Deployment Group'
        condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test')
        environment: 'TestEnvironment'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - powershell: |
                    Install-Module -Name powershell-yaml -Force -Scope CurrentUser
                    $config = Import-Yaml -Path "../config.yml"
                    $env:TGRP_FOLDER_PATH = $config.variables.TGRP_FOLDER_PATH

                    $organization = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
                    $project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
                    $buildId = "$(Build.BuildId)"
                    $patToken = "$(System.AccessToken)"

                    $uri = "$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/changes?api-version=6.0"
                    $headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $patToken" }

                    $changedFiles = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers |
                                    ForEach-Object { $_.value.items.path }

                    Write-Host "Changed files:"
                    $changedFiles | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }

                    $changedFilesPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/changedFiles.txt"
                    $changedFiles | Out-File -FilePath $changedFilesPath

                    $scriptPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/scripts/update-aip.ps1"
                    Write-Host "Running PowerShell script at: $scriptPath"
                    & $scriptPath -ChangedFilesPath $changedFilesPath
                  displayName: 'Get Changed Files and Run PowerShell script'
                  env:
                    SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
                    MES_SERVER_USERNAME: $(MES_SERVER_USERNAME)
                    MES_SERVER_PASSWORD: $(MES_SERVER_PASSWORD)
                    TEST_SERVER_IP: $(TEST_SERVER_IP)
                    PROD_SERVER_IP: $(PROD_SERVER_IP)

      - deployment: DeployToMain
        displayName: 'Deploy to Main Deployment Group'
        condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')
        environment: 'MainEnvironment'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - powershell: |
                    Install-Module -Name powershell-yaml -Force -Scope CurrentUser
                    $config = Import-Yaml -Path "../config.yml"
                    $env:TGRP_FOLDER_PATH = $config.variables.TGRP_FOLDER_PATH

                    $organization = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
                    $project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
                    $buildId = "$(Build.BuildId)"
                    $patToken = "$(System.AccessToken)"

                    $uri = "$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/changes?api-version=6.0"
                    $headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $patToken" }

                    $changedFiles = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers |
                                    ForEach-Object { $_.value.items.path }

                    Write-Host "Changed files:"
                    $changedFiles | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }

                    $changedFilesPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/changedFiles.txt"
                    $changedFiles | Out-File -FilePath $changedFilesPath

                    $scriptPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/scripts/update-aip.ps1"
                    Write-Host "Running PowerShell script at: $scriptPath"
                    & $scriptPath -ChangedFilesPath $changedFilesPath
                  displayName: 'Get Changed Files and Run PowerShell script'
                  env:
                    SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
                    MES_SERVER_USERNAME: $(MES_SERVER_USERNAME)
                    MES_SERVER_PASSWORD: $(MES_SERVER_PASSWORD)
                    TEST_SERVER_IP: $(TEST_SERVER_IP)
                    PROD_SERVER_IP: $(PROD_SERVER_IP)


.ps1 is a file extension for Powershell files. Do you need to run a Powershell script to get the variable value or do you want to read a static value from a file, let's say a text or json file?

Exactly, I want to read a static value from a file

You can for example Convert a JSON file to a custom Powershell object.

I'm still trying to understand your scenario. What is this static value used for? Can't you use a variables template or a variables group in your pipeline?

You might simply dot-source your config script: $config = . ..\Config.ps1 but that would open the door for code injections therefore you better create a PowerShell data (.Psd1) file and use Import-PowerShellDataFile: $Config = Import-PowerShellDataFile ..\Config.psd1

Where do you have the variable? In config.ps1 or config.yml, or some other files? Please show the file content snippet to be more clear. Are you looking for a config,ps1 to read the variable from the file?


I want it to read a variable from config.ps1 file and set a env variable with it.
I want to read a static value from a file

Instead of using the following snippet:
$config = Import-Yaml -Path "../config.yml"
$env:TGRP_FOLDER_PATH = $config.variables.TGRP_FOLDER_PATH

Try using a variable defined in the pipeline or a in a variables template?
For example, a variable defined as follows:
variables:
  - name: TGRP_FOLDER_PATH
    value: /my/folder/

Will be accessible as an environment variable using macro syntax $(TGRP_FOLDER_PATH).
Example
Using variables templates for each environment:
# /pipelines/variables/main-variables.yaml

variables:
  - name: TGRP_FOLDER_PATH
    value: /my/main/folder/

# /pipelines/variables/test-variables.yaml

variables:
  - name: TGRP_FOLDER_PATH
    value: /my/test/folder/

Using each template in a different job:
# /pipelines/my-pipeline.yaml

stages:
  - stage: DeployToServer
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployToTest
        displayName: 'Deploy to Test Deployment Group'
        condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test')
        environment: 'TestEnvironment'
        variables:
          - template: /pipelines/variables/test-variables.yaml # <---------- reference variables template
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: none
                - powershell: |

                    echo "$(TGRP_FOLDER_PATH)" # Output: /my/test/folder/

                    # rest of the script here
                  displayName: 'Get Changed Files and Run PowerShell script'

      - deployment: DeployToMain
        displayName: 'Deploy to Main Deployment Group'
        condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')
        environment: 'MainEnvironment'
        variables:
          - template: /pipelines/variables/main-variables.yaml # <---------- reference variables template
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: none
                - powershell: |

                    echo "$(TGRP_FOLDER_PATH)" # Output: /my/main/folder/

                    # rest of the script here
                  displayName: 'Get Changed Files and Run PowerShell script'


After you grant the variable value in config.ps1, you can use logging command to define a new variable in config.ps1. The new variable(non-secret type) will be automatically mapped as environment and you can use it in next task.
My config.ps1 file, it gets variable from yml file:
#config.ps1
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Install-Module -Name powershell-yaml -Force -Scope CurrentUser
$config = Get-Content -Raw -Path "./config.yml" | ConvertFrom-Yaml
$env:TGRP_FOLDER_PATH = $config.variables.TGRP_FOLDER_PATH
write-host $env:TGRP_FOLDER_PATH
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVariable;]$env:TGRP_FOLDER_PATH"

The yml file content, if it's other type files, please change accordingly.
variables:
  TGRP_FOLDER_PATH: "C:/path/to/your/folder"
  TEST_NEWVALUE: "testnew"
.....

The pipeline sample:
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: 'config.ps1'

- powershell: |
   echo $(MyVariable)
   echo $env:MyVariable          
   Get-ChildItem Env:

The pipeline result in 2nd powershell task, it can get new environment MyVariable value.

